# How to find common strings in elements of the same list (not using intersection)

Tags: python

I am having a list like

```
a=['foo', 'boo', 'foo_ext', 'doo']
```

I want to find if I have elements that differ by a given string, for example, `_ext` in my case - so the output should return that I have 'foo' and 'foo_ext'

I ve tried with intersection, but that returns exact matches, not "partial" ones like I need..

Comment: why are foo and foo_ext considered common yet the other 3 share common strings except one letter?

Comment: what if one of the string `'_extfoo'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find those elements like that

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        if a[i] in a[j] or a[j] in a[i]:
            print(a[i],a[j])
```

The output is `foo foo_ext`.

Edit : I am not sure this answer your problem. Do you want only elements which differ by the particular string `_ext`?

Comment: Correct, they should differ by a particular string